# Creating Shopping List - Local Storage (Ionic 2 / Angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am creating a recipe app whereby you click a button and it will add the selection of ingredients to the shopping list page. I have managed to this but I am struggling with allowing more than 1 to be recipe to the list, as well as when I click the button to add it will display but if I go back and click the tab nothing will display.

My button to add items to shopping list  (Details Page)

```
<div class="ingredients"> 
    <h1>Ingredients</h1>
    <div class="shopping-list">
        <ion-icon name="ios-cart"></ion-icon>
        <h1 (click)="submit(api.ingredientLines)">Add to shopping list</h1> 
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of api?.ingredientLines"><span>{{item}}</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

.ts file (Details Page)

```
submit(ingredientLines) {
    console.log(ingredientLines);
    this.navCtrl.push(ShoppingListPage, {ingredientLines: ingredientLines});
}
```

Shopping List page

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of ingredientLines">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span>{{item}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

shopping list.ts

```
export class ShoppingListPage {

  public ingredientLines;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
      this.ingredientLines = navParams.get('ingredientLines');  
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
      console.log('ionViewDidLoad ShoppingListPage');
      console.log(this.ingredientLines);
  }

}
```

Issue visible https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-R_9Tz7UUk&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I dont get one thing, you are getting from params. and then pushing to the controller. It doenst make sense to me.

Comment: can u create a working plunker?